# How To add css support in mpdf php library

Tags: javascript, php, css, image, mpdf

I am creating html designs like this image:

[image]

I am using the `mdd` library to create a `pdf` of the current design.

I am unable to create a proper `pdf` of my design because pdf does not support `css : display:inline-block`.

How can I add `css : display:inline-block` support to `mpdf`?

Comment: You could try using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ which uses the full webkit engine. You'll have to get PHP to run a command, and you'll need server access to install it all... but it's an option if you do have all of the above. You can then just create your designs in normal HTML + CSS.

Comment: I can create a pdf by using float left, But dosent work with hexagone or other zig zag shape